# Sort string into a list on python

Tags: python

I need to make a string `'abcdef'` into a list `['ab', 'cd', 'ef']` on python 
I tried using `list()` but it returns `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',' 'e, 'f']`

Can anyone help please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
s = "abcdef"
[''.join(x) for x in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])]
# ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

---

Or

```
[s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
# ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an extra function you could use something like this:

```
def grouper(string, size):
    i = 0
    while i < len(string):
        yield string[i:i+size]
        i += size
```

This is a generator so you need to collect all parts of it, for example by using `list`:

```
>>> list(grouper('abcdef', 3))
['abc', 'def']
>>> list(grouper('abcdef', 2))  # <-- that's what you want.
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```